# what is mean by "suppress results from generated code"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

I am using Visual Studio 2008 team system. I have C project. I went to project properties and in the code analysis section. I wonder what is mean by

```
`suppress results from generated code`
```

Can someone explain what does this option do when I set it yes or no?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Suppress results from generated code check box on the Code Analysis property page of a project enables you to select whether you want to see Code Analysis warnings from code generated by a third-party tool.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742298.aspx